# Swift built-in protocol could be redeclared? Why?

Tags: swift, protocols, declaration

I found a very confusing thing: we can redeclare the swift build-in protocol, anyone, such as `Sequence` and `UITableViewDelegate`. No compile error, even no warning. Can someone explain me why? If that's the truth, how would it affect the built-in ones?

Comment: You can use the built-in ones by using the library name prefix such as `UIKit.UITableViewDelegate` or `Foundation.Sequence`

Comment: So that's because protocol is declared in it's own namespace, protocol with the same name in different module don't affect each other. Can I say so?

Comment: Yep, exactly. They are in different module and Swift makes those protocols public in a way that you don't have to specify the module's name. But whenever you create your own, you need to specify it.

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found a very confusing thing: we can redeclare the swift build-in protocol, anyone, such as Sequence and UITableViewDelegate. No compile error, even no warning. Can someone explain me why?

Classes, structs, enums, protocols and globals are all name spaced by the module name. If you declare a protocol called `Sequence` in your application `MyApp`, its full name will be `MyApp.Sequence`. As a convenience, if you omit the module part of the name, the compiler will try to guess what it is.

> If that's the truth, how would it affect the built-in ones?

If you do define something with the same name as a type in one of the system modules, the compiler will use your version for preference in the same module. Other people's code including that in the Apple frameworks will be unaffected. You can disambiguate by specifying the module name of the type. So in `MyApp` you can use the original `Sequence` by writing `Swift.Sequence` (`Swift` is the module name for the Swift standard library types).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in ones by using the library name prefix such as `UIKit.UITableViewDelegate` or `Foundation.Sequence`.

They are in a different module and Swift makes those protocols public in a way that you don't have to specify the module's name. But whenever you create your own, you need to specify it. This rule works for every cases.